# Incorrect Domain model with ef

Tags: entity-framework, model, entity-relationship, anti-patterns

I have a little problem with Entity Framework when trying to model the real life
problem.
I have 2 entity like this :

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Task> Tasks{ get; set; }
    }


 public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Person Assignee{ get; set; }
        public Person Assigner{ get; set; }
    }
```

but if I want to use Entity framework,it forces me to change my model like this that it is different from real life !!

```
 public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Task> AssigneesTasks{ get; set; }
            public ICollection<Task> AssignerTasks{ get; set; }
        }
```

(i just have single one-to-many relation in fact)

what is the solution to keep my model according to real life model?

Comment: Why do you think a single 1-many relationship is the correct model?

Comment: how you can explain two 1-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you might want to know what tasks a person has assigned to them, and what tasks they have assigned to others. If you don't want both Navigation properties you don't need them in EF. But you *do* need to tell EF which relationship the Navigation Property is for.  EG:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Assignee")]
        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }


    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Person Assignee { get; set; }
        public Person Assigner { get; set; }
    }
```